# Fundamental group and curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

**Is there any paper about the $\pi_1$ group and curvature ?**

Because  how close a curve depends on the curvature near the curve . I think there must have some condition which decide  whether there is closed curve on manifold. Besides,     curvature decide the genus.So, I guess there should be some connection between fundamental group and curvature.

If there are any unclear , sorry for my poor English.

Comment: The following sentence is a bit reductionist, but fun to write: there is a whole field on the relation between the topology of a space and its curvature, known as differential geometry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are four theorems from Riemannian geometry that might interest you.  All of them can be found (with proofs) in Chapters 9 and 12 of Manfredo do Carmo's book "Riemannian Geometry."

**Bonnet-Myers Theorem:** Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold with $\text{Ric}(g) \geq k > 0$ for some constant $k > 0$.  Then $M$ is compact and $\pi_1(M)$ is finite.

**Synge Theorem:** Let $(M^{2n},g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold that is orientable, even-dimensional, and having positive sectional curvature.  Then $\pi_1(M) = 0$.

**Theorem (Preissman):** Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with negative sectional curvature.  Then $\pi_1(M)$ is not abelian.

**Theorem (Byers):** Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with negative sectional curvature.  Then every solvable subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$ is either the identity itself or is infinite cyclic.  Moreover, $\pi_1(M)$ has no cyclic subgroup of finite index.

Comment: I read too little.

Comment: After all these years, I happen to see the proof of Byers' theorem today. The emotion is hard to say.

Answer (score 2):

Too late, But for further readers. A paper of *J. Milnor* about growth function of the fundamental group is also useful:

J. Milnor (1968), [A note on curvature and fundamental group](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214501132).