# Order of the fundamental group from the metric of a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, curvature

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact manifold of dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is there any formula (or is it possible) to find the *[order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) of the [fundamental group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group)*, $\pi_1(M)$ using the metric of the manifold in general?

Or in other words, how can we conclude if a manifold is multiply-connected *i.e.* $\text {order}\left[\pi_1(M)\right] \ge 2$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3043802/1049412)) using the metric $g$ in general?

I know there are some theorems regarding the properties of fundamental group of a Riemannian manifold, as stated in ["Fundamental group and curvature"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1823946/1049412), but I'm searching for any theorem regarding the direct relation between the order of $\pi_1(M)$ and the metric.

**Context:** As [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) connects the geometry and the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Topological_definition) (a topological invariant) of a compact $2$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, likewise there should be an other theorem which will connect the order of the fundamental group (again a topological invariant) and the metric (geometry) of that manifold.

Answer (score 5):

If a compact manifold has curvature $K\leq 0$, the Cartan-Hadamard theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) tells us that its universal cover is diffeomorphic to $\bf R ^n$, hence non compact so that its fundamental group is infinite.

For finite groups I dont think that such can exists. Consider for instance  lens spaces $S^{2n-1}/C_k$ obtained by taking the quotient of the unit sphere of $C^n$ by a cyclic group of order $k$ acting diagonnaly. These spaces have all curvature equal to $+1$, and fundamental group cyclic of order $k$.

More generally a finite cover of a manifold has same curvature bounds, but a fundamental group of smaller order, whenever finite.

Comment: Another connection between geometry and topology is that a positive lower bound on the Ricci tensor yields compactness and finiteness of the fundamental group

Comment: **Just a doubt:** If for $K\le0$, the fundamental group is infinite, then the manifold can never be simply-connected, right? As simply-connected manifold, by definition, needs trivial fundamental group *i.e.* of $\text{order}\left[\pi_1\right] = 1$. Thus any manifold with non-positive sectional curvature has to be multiply-connected. Is it the case always?

Comment: Certainly, if you add the word "compact". $R^n$ is a simply connected manifold with $k=0$. it is not compact. The universal cover a a compact manifold with non positive curvature is always diffeomrophic to $R^n$.